# How to use SQL loader when loading from remote data file?

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load data in Oracle database from BCP files.
The Oracle database server is located on remote machine. In my control file I have added path to BCP file as - `load data INFILE 'C:\path\to\bcpFile.txt'`. This does not work if BCP files are not on same machine as DB server. One option I found is to create network mapping on my windows machine to the linux DB server. But this has manual overhead. I learned we can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to fetch data files, I would like see an example for this.

Comment: Why not install the full Oracle Client (includes SQL Loader) on a (your) Windows computer (e.g. where BCP file is located)?

Comment: that solves it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install the full Oracle Client which includes SQL Loader on your Windows Computer**

SQL Loader is included with full Oracle Client installs.

Once installed, make sure your `infile` section properly references your datafile using the correct [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-7EBEA709-4192-4B5A-A3FA-450D41BE2EC7.htm#SUTIL1063).

With the path you provided, this section would look like this:

`INFILE 'C:\path\to\bcpFile.txt'`

Comment: While trying to load data in remote database server if data files are present on the remote server can I invoke sqlldr and instruct it to find datafiles on db server?

Comment: @noobCoder if your files are on the db server (as opposed to the remote server), then sql loader is part of the installation of an Oracle database. It sounds like it would make sense to execute sql loader on the db server.